# Replacing an array item based on a property in the item

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

I have the following JSON in an external file:

```
{
    "Name": "Service Provider",
    "Categories": [
        {
            "Name": "Identity",
            "Mandatory": false
        },
        {
            "Name": "Contat Information",
            "Mandatory": false
        },
        {
            "Name": "Service Fields",
            "Mandatory": false
        },
        {
            "Name": "Addresses",
            "Mandatory": false
        },
        {
            "Name": "Bank Accounts",
            "Mandatory": false
        }
    ]
}
```

If I would like to replace, for example, the "Identity" category to look something like this in memory:

```
{
    "Name": "Identity",
    "Mandatory": true,
    ...
}
```

I could write something like this:

```
JObject jObject = return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(File.ReadAllText(path));

// "GetNewIdentity()" gets a JObject representing the new "Identity" JSON shown above
jObject["Categories"][0] = GetNewIdentity();
```

The problem is that I need to know what category to change when writing the code. What if I know which category to change only at runtime?

That is why I want to find the category to replace in the array using its `Name` property. I have tried the following code:

```
// "name" comes from a different place.
result["Categories"].Single(c => c["Name"].Equals(name)) = GetNewIdentity();
```

but because I am trying to assign the value to a returned value and not to a variable, I get the following error:

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or
>   indexer

I would also like that the order of categories would be preserved after the replacement. How can I accomplish this?

---

**Note:**

I do not have, or can have, POCO classes representing the JSON.

Comment: Do you have classes you can deserialize this JSON to?

Comment: [Modifying JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ModifyJson.htm)(first result from search)

Comment: *"How can I accomplish this?*" - what exactly? Typically you would deserialize, change value and then serialize json. What is input data? Is this json a file, a string or what? What it should be after you change the value?

Comment: I would definitely go for creating POCO classes unless of course design is not suitable

Comment: @Sinatr Please review the changes I have made to the question and let me know if something isn't clear enough.

Comment: @Reniuz - Using the code in the link I could replace the entire array. I am looking for a way of replacing only one item in the array based on it's `Name` property. If the link you provided does help me get there, I do no understand how, and I will be grateful if you could demonstrate it in an answer.

Comment: How you imagine the replacement of that element? In memory? In file?

Comment: @Reniuz - In memory. Edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how you can do it. What you need is access the property you wish and replace a value of it.

```
void Main()
{
    JObject jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(File.ReadAllText(path));
    JObject newCategory = new JObject();
    newCategory.Add("Name", "Identity");
    newCategory.Add("Mandatory", "false");
    newCategory.Add("NewProp", "Yes");
    ReplaceCategoryValue(jObject, "Identity", newCategory);

    Console.WriteLine(jObject.ToString());
}

void ReplaceCategoryValue(JObject jObject, string categoryName, JObject newCategory)
{
    JToken categories = jObject["Categories"];
    JObject targetCategory = categories.Children<JObject>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Property("Name").Value.ToString() == categoryName);
    targetCategory.Replace(newCategory);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This code targets a property, while I want to target the object containing the property. Meaning, this code replaces the value of the "Name" property instead of the object containing the "Name" Property - the category itself.

Comment: Ahh sorry misunderstood your aim. I am still not sure what's the conditions of search, but check the updated answer. I think you are looking for Replace method.

Comment: Your code works perfectly, you understood the question correctly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I still do not understand why you wouldn't define a POCO. Here have a look at this one.
Here are your POCOS

```
public class MyRootObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Mandatory { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how you use it

```
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyRootObject>(Resource.Json);
//name comes from somewhere else like in the question
var identity = rootObject.Categories.Single(c => c.Name == name);
identity.Mandatory = GetNewIdentity();
```

Comment: I cannot use POCO classes for this because that is what my senior said. :)

Comment: If seniors were always right we'd still think the earth is flat.